# raise ValueError and logging in one step

Tags: python-3.x

What is the best way to raise an error and write the error to a log file in one step?

I often want to raise an error, but i want to write the error-message to a logfile too. Is there a more elegant way than in the code below?

```
errormessage = 'blablabla!'
logger.critical(errormessage)
raise ValueError(errormessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could write a function to combine them, but there is another way to think of this: separating the two steps is actually a good thing because *in general* the UX for a piece of code is some layers above the point at which you detect and raise the exception. In between the two, there may be layers which can detect and recover from the exception.

That's why logging an error is normally kept separate from detecting the exceptional situation.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to do it:

```
def log_error(error_type, message):
    logger.critical(message)
    return error_type(message)
```

Then call the code as such:

```
raise log_error(ValueError, 'blablabla!')
```